# Como cargar un select independiente con AJAX, JQuery bajo en framework de Codeigniter version 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter-4

Hola necesito llenar un select trayendo los datos desde la base de datos, tengo el siguiente codigo:
Vista: Aqui realizo una vista con solo el select que deseo llenar, realizando los llamados a las diferentes librerias de script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <title>BOOKING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> BOOKING</h1>
    <form>
        <select id="BrandSelect" name="BrandSelect">
            <option value="">Select a Brand</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
   
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?=base_url('llenarlistasMarca') ?>',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var options = "<option value=''>Select a brand</option>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].description + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#BrandSelect").html(options);
                }
                
            });
        });
    

</script>
</html>
```

En el código anterior me indica que no consigue la pagina tiene un error 404´. Al colocarlo de la manera que se muestra a continuación no me indica error me indica que todo ok pero no me llena el combo

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'book',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var options = "<option value=''>Select a brand</option>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].description + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#BrandSelect").html(options);
                }
                
            });
        });
```

Controlador: Aquí realizo el llamado al Modelo creado utilizando la las funciones de Query Builder

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\BrandModel;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Home extends BaseController
{
   
    public function llenarlistasMarca()
    {
        $brandModel = new BrandModel();
        $brand = $brandModel->findAll();
        echo 'hola';
        print_r($brand);
    }
}
?>
```

Modelo:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class BrandModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_brand';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['description'];
}
?>
```

Routes

```
$routes->post('llenarlistasMarca', 'Home::llenarlistasMarca');
```

Al ejecutar esto me invalida el codigo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que la petición devuelve un error 404, es lo primero que debes solventar y no tiene que ver con la forma en la que se rellena el select. Revisa las rutas y asegúrate de que la petición a llenarListasMarca te devuelva datos. Desupués, edita la pregunta añadiendo la respuesta de la petición.

Comment: Cuando le elimino la introduccion de codigo php me indica que encuentra la pagina pero no hace llamado a la funcion que se encuentra en el controlador. Esta funcion la ensaye en otra pagina y si funciona